# WSO2 doesn't show errors

Tags: wso2

I have a problem with the WSO2 application server, and try catch error in the output file wso2carbon.log, but the applcation doesn't show error, my log4j file is:

https://gist.github.com/gururea/104e6e7db83849199309

And Follow this [steps](https://docs.wso2.org/display/AS521/Introduction+to+Logging?src=search).

I try setting this debug mode, error mode, all modes, and doesn't show errors. I developed application with wso2 carbon IDE.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cant find any logs, Deploy some debug points by yourself in the relevant component.  Please follow this [blog post](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-do-process-debug-logs-and.html).

Hope this might helps!